# Laravel Cashier Webhook: Get Amount and Invoice Details

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel 5.3 with Cashier for Stripe. I have set-up a custom controller extending the `CashierController` for handling Webhooks as per the Docs. In this Webhook, how can I get the amount that was charged and invoice details from `$payload`?

```
public function handleInvoicePaymentFailed($payload)
     {
         // Handle The Event
         $customer = $this->getBillable($payload['data']['object']['customer']);

         // NEXT - HOW TO GET THE AMOUNT THAT WAS CHARGED AND INVOICE NUMBER??


         return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
     }
```

I want to get the following info from that:

1. Amount
2. Invoice Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$payload['data']['object']['amount_due']` to get the amount due and `$payload['data']['object']['id']` to get the stripe invoice id.

Go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events, click on the event and look at the Event Data there.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you heaps @CUGreen

Comment: +1 for the events link in dashboard. I was searching the docs to see the events list for webhook but I was unable to locate it. Thank you. Now it makes things easy.